# Reactor apply Flux to each emission of other Flux?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I have two `Flux` objects eg.:

`Flux<Item>` and `Flux<Transformation>`

```
data class Item(val value: Int)

data class Transformation(val type: String, val value: Int)
```

I would like to apply all transformations to each item - something like:

```
var item = Item(15)

val transformations = listOf(Transformation(type = "MULTIPLY", value = 8), ...)

transformations.forEach {
  if (it.type == "MULTIPLY") {
    item = Item(item.value * it.value) 
  }
}
```

but when having `Flux`'es of `Item` and `Transformation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `java.util.function.UnaryOperator` instead of `Transformation` class.
Hope this Java example could help you:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Flux<Item> items = Flux.just(new Item(10), new Item(20));
    Flux<UnaryOperator<Item>> transformations = Flux.just(
            item -> new Item(item.value * 8),
            item -> new Item(item.value - 3));

    Flux<Item> transformed = items.flatMap(item -> transformations
            .collectList()
            .map(unaryOperators -> transformFunction(unaryOperators)
                    .apply(item)));

    System.out.println(transformed.collectList().block());
}

Function<Item, Item> transformFunction(List<UnaryOperator<Item>> itemUnaryOperators) {
    Function<Item, Item> transformFunction = UnaryOperator.identity();
    for (UnaryOperator<Item> itemUnaryOperator : itemUnaryOperators) {
        transformFunction = transformFunction.andThen(itemUnaryOperator);
    }
    return transformFunction;
}
```

Comment: only problem with this is that items are duplicated by number of transformations which is not what I want

Comment: Do you want to chain transformations for each item?

Comment: exactly, I want to apply all transformations to each item so (eg. one item and ten transformations should produce one item but with ten transformations applied)

Comment: And what about sequence of transformations? Does it matter?

Comment: you mean if the order of sequence matters? No, it does not matter, only requirement is to apply each transformation on item

Comment: so in case you provided it should be `((10 * 8) - 3), ((20 * 8) -3)`

Comment: I have edited the answer. But I'm afraid that the order of transformations could play important role in the real system. So maybe, it would be better to have list of transformations